# PHP 5: return by ref method produces unexpected results

Tags: php, testing, pointers, byref

I created a simple class to manage a tree data structure which seemed to behave strangely (code to follow). When it became apparent that this was not a mistake by me I created a test case which produced equally puzzling behavior. This is the same in 5.3 and 5.4.

This is my test case:

```
<?php
class testcaseA {
    public function __construct($one=0, $two=1, $three=2) {
        $this->obj = new testcaseB($one++, $three, $two);
    }
    public function &get($what){
        return $this->obj->get($what);
    } 
}
class testcaseB {
    public function __construct($one, &$two, &$three) {
        $this->one=$one;
        $this->two=$two;
        $this->three=$three;
        echo "\$one={$one}";
    }
    public function &get($what){
        echo "<p>You asked for $what. $what ain't no country I ever heard of.<br />";
        echo "Check: [{$this->one}], {$this->two}, {$this->three}. Is this thing on?</p>";
        $this->obj[$what] = new testcaseB($this->one++,$this->two,$this->three);
        return $this->obj[$what];
    } 
}
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$bob = new testcaseA();
$bob->get("What")->get("Spam")->get("America");
$bob->get("What")->get("EU")->get("France");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($bob);
```

Now the output that I expected was to see the value for $one increment 1,2,3,1,2,3 and produce a tree shape.

This is the output I actually got:

```
$one=0

You asked for What. What ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [0], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=0

You asked for Spam. Spam ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [0], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=0

You asked for America. America ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [0], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=0

You asked for What. What ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [1], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=1

You asked for EU. EU ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [1], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=1

You asked for France. France ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [1], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=1

testcaseA Object
(
    [obj] => testcaseB Object
        (
            [one] => 2
            [two] => 2
            [three] => 1
            [obj] => Array
                (
                    [What] => testcaseB Object
                        (
                            [one] => 2
                            [two] => 2
                            [three] => 1
                            [obj] => Array
                                (
                                    [EU] => testcaseB Object
                                        (
                                            [one] => 2
                                            [two] => 2
                                            [three] => 1
                                            [obj] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [France] => testcaseB Object
                                                        (
                                                            [one] => 1
                                                            [two] => 2
                                                            [three] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This confused me at first but I wondered if maybe the chained usage was setting values in a way I was not expecting.

So I tried this which I added after the previous code:

```
...same classes and initial code as before...
$a=$bob->get("What");
$b=$a->get("Spam");
$c=$b->get("America");
//$bob->get("What")
$d=$a->get("EU");
$e=$d->get("France");  
print_r($bob);
```

This produced a different but still unpredictable set of results.

```
You asked for What. What ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [2], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=2

You asked for Spam. Spam ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [2], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=2

You asked for America. America ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [2], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=2

You asked for EU. EU ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [3], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=3

You asked for France. France ain't no country I ever heard of.
Check: [3], 2, 1. Is this thing on?
$one=3testcaseA Object
(
    [obj] => testcaseB Object
        (
            [one] => 3
            [two] => 2
            [three] => 1
            [obj] => Array
                (
                    [What] => testcaseB Object
                        (
                            [one] => 4
                            [two] => 2
                            [three] => 1
                            [obj] => Array
                                (
                                    [Spam] => testcaseB Object
                                        (
                                            [one] => 3
                                            [two] => 2
                                            [three] => 1
                                            [obj] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [America] => testcaseB Object
                                                        (
                                                            [one] => 2
                                                            [two] => 2
                                                            [three] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [EU] => testcaseB Object
                                        (
                                            [one] => 4
                                            [two] => 2
                                            [three] => 1
                                            [obj] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [France] => testcaseB Object
                                                        (
                                                            [one] => 3
                                                            [two] => 2
                                                            [three] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is still not the behavior that I am after but it is closer. What I need is to use a chain of objects to traverse the tree (as with the first case), a pointer to the values $two and $three which in the real case are arrays and not swapped about. What I don't want to do is copy objects needlessly.

On the other hand I do need to have all the objects share a single pair of variables which they all use.

My guess is that the method `get()` could afford to be `byval` rather than `byref` although instinctively this seems wrong.

Can anyone explain what the `$one` value is doing?

Also can anyone help me understand the behavior of the first test case especially to the values in the array the first time?

**UPDATE**

Making use of the awesome suggestions our test case now looks like:

```
class testcaseA {
    public function __construct($one=0, $two=1, $three=2) {
        $this->obj = new testcaseB(++$one, $three, $two);
    }
    public function &get($what){
        return $this->obj->get($what);
    } 
}
class testcaseB {
    public function __construct($one, &$two, &$three) {
        $this->one=$one;
        $this->two=$two;
        $this->three=$three;
        echo "[New:\$one={$one}]:";
    }
    //public function &get($what){
    public function &get($what){
        //echo "<p>You asked for $what. $what ain't no country I ever heard of.<br />";
        echo "Get:{$what}:[{$this->one}]<br />";
        if(!isset($this->obj[$what])){
            $this->obj[$what] = new testcaseB(++$this->one,$this->two,$this->three);
        }
        return $this->obj[$what];
    } 
}
echo "STARTING:<br />";
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "REALLY STARTING:<br />";
echo "<pre>";
echo "<p>One at a time:</p>";
$bob = new testcaseA();
$a=$bob->get("What");
$b=$a->get("Spam");
$c=$b->get("America");
$d=$a->get("EU");
$e=$d->get("France"); 
echo "<br />";
print_r($bob); 
echo "<p>Chained:</p>";
$bobby = new testcaseA();
$bobby->get("What")->get("Spam")->get("America");
$bobby->get("What")->get("EU")->get("France");
echo "<br />";
print_r($bob);
```

The out put of which is:

```
STARTING:
REALLY STARTING:

One at a time:
[New:$one=1]:Get:What:[1]
[New:$one=2]:Get:Spam:[2]
[New:$one=3]:Get:America:[3]
[New:$one=4]:Get:EU:[3]
[New:$one=4]:Get:France:[4]
[New:$one=5]:
testcaseA Object
(
    [obj] => testcaseB Object
        (
            [one] => 2
            [two] => 2
            [three] => 1
            [obj] => Array
                (
                    [What] => testcaseB Object
                        (
                            [one] => 4
                            [two] => 2
                            [three] => 1
                            [obj] => Array
                                (
                                    [Spam] => testcaseB Object
                                        (
                                            [one] => 4
                                            [two] => 2
                                            [three] => 1
                                            [obj] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [America] => testcaseB Object
                                                        (
                                                            [one] => 4
                                                            [two] => 2
                                                            [three] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [EU] => testcaseB Object
                                        (
                                            [one] => 5
                                            [two] => 2
                                            [three] => 1
                                            [obj] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [France] => testcaseB Object
                                                        (
                                                            [one] => 5
                                                            [two] => 2
                                                            [three] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)

Chained:
[New:$one=1]:Get:What:[1]
[New:$one=2]:Get:Spam:[2]
[New:$one=3]:Get:America:[3]
[New:$one=4]:Get:What:[2]
Get:EU:[3]
[New:$one=4]:Get:France:[4]
[New:$one=5]:
testcaseA Object
(
    [obj] => testcaseB Object
        (
            [one] => 2
            [two] => 2
            [three] => 1
            [obj] => Array
                (
                    [What] => testcaseB Object
                        (
                            [one] => 4
                            [two] => 2
                            [three] => 1
                            [obj] => Array
                                (
                                    [Spam] => testcaseB Object
                                        (
                                            [one] => 4
                                            [two] => 2
                                            [three] => 1
                                            [obj] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [America] => testcaseB Object
                                                        (
                                                            [one] => 4
                                                            [two] => 2
                                                            [three] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [EU] => testcaseB Object
                                        (
                                            [one] => 5
                                            [two] => 2
                                            [three] => 1
                                            [obj] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [France] => testcaseB Object
                                                        (
                                                            [one] => 5
                                                            [two] => 2
                                                            [three] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The output numbers seem right but the `$one` are off in the stack.

Comment: Interestingly I do not get expected behavior when get becomes a normal byval function.

Comment: Running the two versions (one after another and chain) in the other order still has chain doing bad things to the stack of objects. And yes I have now been schooled in the fact that $i++ is not the same as ++$i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are confused about (and I *think* I do) you have run into the subtle difference between [pre- and post-increment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php). This can be most easily demonstrated in code:

```
$a = 1;
echo $a++; // 1
echo $a;   // 2
```

On the other hand:

```
$a = 1;
echo ++$a; // 2
echo $a;   // 2
```

Basically, by placing `++` *before* the value you increment, you will get the new value. By placing it after (as you have done) you will get the old value.

I think the key line in your code is this:

```
$this->obj[$what] = new testcaseB($this->one++,$this->two,$this->three);
```

...should be this:

```
$this->obj[$what] = new testcaseB(++$this->one,$this->two,$this->three);
```

With the post-increment, the initial value of `$this->one` will be carried through all subsequent iterations.

As a side note, I don't think you need to worry about returning by reference here, since all objects in PHP5 are passed by reference anyway.

Comment: Well that explains the values doing their own thing. I'll be sure to watch out for that in the future. The thing that has gotten me really stuck is that the object $bob is not a tree - "spam" and "America" are missing in the first instance.

Comment: @MatthewBrown OK one second let me take another look.

Comment: Awesome thanks. In my original (non trivial example) a `$this->value` doesn't seem to exist in a method called `&get($child)` but was available all other places. The $one++ was simply meant to represent that (embarrassingly I missed a subtle difference).

Comment: @MatthewBrown OK right I've figured it out. The problem line is actually the same one as I mentioned above. Because you don't check whether `$this->obj[$what]` already exists before you create a new object, you are overwriting the instance from the previous iteration. All you need to do to fix this is prefix the line with `if (!isset($this->obj[$what]))`. PS I love variables with names like `$bob`

Comment: That also helps to explain the behavior of the test case. However:
`$bobby->get("What")->get("Spam")->get("America");`
`$bobby->get("What")->get("EU")->get("France");`
Produces 1 and 3 when `get("What")` is called. That's not to say that your answer(s) have not been right on the money just that my test case was rubbish.

Comment: It looks like `$one` is acting like a reference. (PS `$bob` is a must in all projects)

Comment: @MatthewBrown What are the numbers supposed to represent? The number of child objects? And what are `$two` and `$three` about?

Comment: $two and $three were just there to see if it could keep the values consistent but $one is emulating that the non trivial example has a unique ID from the DB which at `&get($child)` it "forgets" and is 0 in all instances.

Comment: So does each instance represent a row from the DB? The ID of which (presumably) would be retrieved and assigned during the `get()` method?

Comment: That's right. The `&get($child)` also makes the row if it doesn't exist and reloads the shared array (which is everything in the DB). But because the value of $one (in our case) is 0 every time the class makes new rows every page load. I suspect it is for the same reason that the test case numbers are off in the `print_r` but because the real case is a CI framework object the stack printout is too huge to read. Thus the more trivial test case to try and understand what is going on. I'm positive that if I can understand why the numbers in the stack are off I can understand the the main project.

Comment: I suspect that what you really need here, in that case, is a `static` counter in the class incremented only when you actually create a new branch, rather than trying to pass it between instances. That way you are guaranteed a consistent reading and it makes it much less complicated. Or have I missed the point?

Comment: If you look at the print_r in the update you can see the stack has some odd values.

Comment: @MatthewBrown Are you expecting to see the numbers increment by one as the tree cascades? Essentially I suppose the question is, are you expecting `$one` to represent the depth within the tree so that `Spam` and `EU` have the same value, or for each newly created object to have a unique value for `$one`, so that every value in the range `1 -> n` is represented exactly once where `n` is the number of unique objects that have been created?

Comment: That's right. Although being forced to re-look at this test case has helped me debug the non trivial source of my question.